# How do you avoid losing focus on a contenteditable element when a user clicks outside that element?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, contenteditable

I want to prevent a `contentEditable` area from losing focus if a click is made outside that area.  Some sample HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
<div id="clickThis">
    <p>If you click on this or anywhere for that matter after focusing on Hello, you lose your focus on Hello</p>
</div>
```

Sample Javascript looks as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#content')[0].contentEditable=true;

    $('#clickThis').bind('click',function(e)
    {
        console.log(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

When you click on the `#clickThis` div or anywhere outside the `#content` div, you lose focus on the `#content` div even if you call the click event's `preventDefault` function.

In addition, the range changes the moment the click event is fired, so I can't just return to the previous range after the click has occurred.  Is there a way to maintain the cursor position and focus after a click occurs?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VivekVish/FKDhe/4/

Comment: Well I know it is possible in jeditable, if you'd prefer to use that plugin, it would also give you a lot more power http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable

Comment: My needs are super specific.  I have built an entire WYSIWYG already.  It would be difficult to go back.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  How precisely do you do it in jeditable?  If you could explain it, perhaps I can replicate the functionality.

Comment: It's an option you would pass in, onblur: none, and thanks for not ripping my head off for offering a different solution to the problem ;)

Comment: Try the mousedown event, maybe the range hasn't change at that event

Comment: Thank you, Juan.  That worked perfectly. Preventing default for mousedown did it.  Please make your comment a response so that I can accept it.  And thanks again for the ideas, mazzzzz.  I haven't tried it out.  Perhaps it still works.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Putting Juan's question into an answer, instead of using the click event, you have to use the mousedown event as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#content')[0].contentEditable=true;

    $('#clickThis').bind('mousedown',function(e)
    {
        console.log(window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0).startContainer);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

You can see it working here:

http://jsfiddle.net/FKDhe/7/

Answer (score 3):

The ***answer*** is to add `event.preventDefault()` to the `mouseDown` event.

```
const button = document.getElementById('boldFormat')

button.addEventListener('mousedown', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault() // prevent loss of focus
  document.execCommand('bold', false)
})
```

The problem occurred because the you are listening to the `click` event which causes the `contentEditable` element to lose focus; regardless of whether you run `preventDefault` or not.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `$('#content').focus();` after `e.preventDefault();`
it's not a perfect solution, since it jumps to the beginning, but give it a try.

anyway, are you sure it's a good idea to force the user back to this area? :)

Comment: In my case, yes.  The entire application is a WYSIWYG editor and when the user clicks on a toolbar but misses a button, they have to click on the content position that they were at before and then click on the toolbar button again.  The `$('#content').focus()` solution also suffers from this problem though.  That is, they will have to click to get back to their previous position.

Thanks for the idea.